# Show the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)$ is the same as the number of partitions of $3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(let a partition of $n \in \Bbb N, n>0 $ be a sum of positive integers)

How would you show that the number of different partitions of $3$ is the coefficient of 
$x^3$
in the
expansion of:

$(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)?$

My attempt:

since there are $3$ brackets to choose factors of $x^3$ from, we can say the following:

$ x^3 = x^a x^b x^c, a \in \{0,1,2,3\}, b \in \{0,2\}, c \in \{0,3\}$

The coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion will equal the number of solutions satisfying $ x^3 = x^a x^b x^c$.

$a=0 \Rightarrow b=0 $ and $ c=3$,

$a=1 \Rightarrow b=2 $ and $ c=0$,

$a=2 \Rightarrow$ no solution.

$a=3 \Rightarrow b=0 $ and $ c=0$,

$\Rightarrow$ the coefficient of $x^3$ is $3$ which equals the number of partitions of $3$.

Do I understand what the question is asking? Because I'm wondering if just multiplying the brackets and obtaining the coefficient is an equivalent solution to the question.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "partitions of 3"?

Comment: the number of ways to break 3 into positive integers.

Comment: With what restrictions? Because counting that way, you did not account for $3 = 1+1+1$

Comment: With no restrictions, however, the number of partitions of 3 is 3, I used this method to determine the coefficient of $x^3$ (I don't know why this is equal to the number of partitions of  3) but I am unsure as to whether this is a way to go about it or is there a more systematical way of doing it if you know what I mean?

Comment: The definition of partition is slightly more subtle than the one you gave above, and I suggest becoming very clear on the definition used for the problem statement. It might be the source of your trouble. (Some people allow 0 in a partition, and some do not, for example).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for your information, I've have made an appropriate edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two variations, both being equally valid with respect to the stated problem. Maybe the *second variant* is preferable since it provides some additional insight to the representation of the polynomial.

> **Algebraic variant:**
>
> We calculate the coefficient of $x^3$ of the polynomial and compare it with $p(3)$, the number of partitions.
>
> Since $3$ admits a representation as sum of positive integers without respecting order of summands by 
>   \begin{align*}
> 3&=3\\
> &=2+1\\
> &=1+1+1
> \end{align*}
>   we see $p(3)=3$.
>
> On the other hand using the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a polynomial, we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>         [x^3]&(1+x^3)(1+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\\
>         &=\left([x^3]+[x^0]\right)(1+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\tag{1}\\
>         &=\left([x^3]+[x^1]+[x^0]\right)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\tag{2}\\
>         &=1+1+1\tag{3}\\
>         &=3
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we consider the coefficient of $[x^3]$ in $1+x^3$ and use the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we do the same with $1+x^2$ noting that $[x^0]x^2=0$.
- In (3) we select the coefficients of $1+x+x^2+x^3$ accordingly.

> **Variant based upon generating functions:**
>
> If we want to count the number of partitions of a number $n$, we have to consider summands $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$. The summand $k$ may occur zero, one, two or more times, but at most $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$ times. The contribution of $k$ encoded as powers of $x$ in a generating function is therefore
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+x^k+x^{2k}+\cdots+x^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor k}
> \end{align*}
>
> In case of $p(n)$  with $n=3$ we have to consider the summands $3,2$ and $1$.
>
> - *Summand: $3$* may occur zero or one times giving $\longrightarrow 1+x^3$
> - *Summand: $2$* may occur zero or one times giving $\longrightarrow 1+x^2$
> - *Summand: $1$* may occur zero, one, two or three times $\longrightarrow 1+x+x^2+x^3$
>
> We conclude: $p(3)$ is the coefficient of $x^3$ in
>   \begin{align*}
>         (1+x^3)(1+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You can see the "situation" as I try and depict in this sketch

[image: part_of_3]

For what concerns the partitions of $3$ (and of $2$ and $1$) , all the necessary "pieces" are provided.

*Explanation of the sketch*
When you expand the first polynomial, this will provide a factor $x^k$ to multiply the rest, and $k$ is either $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $3$.
The second polynomial will provide a factor $x^j$ with $j=0,2$, and the third a factor $x^n$ with $n=0,3$.
When then you collect the terms $x^{(j+k+n)}$, grouping together all the terms with the exponent $j+k+n=q$, then each of the various terms will correspond to each one of the partitions of $q$ composed of $0..3$ parts $=1$ +$0..1$ parts $=2$ + $0..1$ parts $=3$, and the resulting coefficient of $x^q$ will be the number of those partitions.

Comment: What do you mean by: "0 to 3 "1"" etc?

Comment: @ConnorGaughan : I have added a brief explanation. For more detailed one you may have a look to lectures explaining the association between formal series and partitions, e.g. [this excellent one](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/PIMS/PIMSLectures.pdf)